# How to sort the result of this query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have theses 2 models : **Bettor** and **User**.

These models are linked between them like that :

For the Bettor :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

For the User :

```
public function bettors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bettor::class);
}
```

I have this query :

```
return Bettor::where('bet_id', $bet->id)
    ->with(['user' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('email');
    }])
    ->get();
```

The result does not sort the users with their emails. But when I read the documentation here, it is possible to do that :

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

I could sort the collection after the query, but of course it would not be the correct method.

So where is my mistake ?

Comment: Do you want to order the relationship data to be in specific order or do you want to get the Bettors ordered based on user's email?

Comment: I want the Bettors ordered based on user's email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things.

1- If you want to order your relationship then it's working fine. The relationship data you're getting is actually getting sorted.

2- If you want to get the `Bettor` sorted on the basis of user's email then:

```
Bettors::query()->where('bet_id', $bet->id)->with('user')->orderBy(User::select('email)->whereColumn('users.id', 'bettors.user_id'))->get();
```

This will return back the results based on relationship's column sorting. What this query is doing is that `orderBy` can take in a sub-query so we are using a sub-query and selecting the email column.

Comment: yes it solved my problem. But I do not know if I will keep this solution, because a little bit complicated to understand. Perhaps I will sort the collection after the query, I am still thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bettor::with('user')->where('bet_id', $bet->id)->get()->sortByDesc('user.email');
```

This will sort the results of the query after eager loading using collection methods and not by a MySQL ORDER BY.

Comment: He mentioned it "I could sort the collection after the query, but of course it would not be the correct method."